# Logical And/Or Operator - Unexpected end Result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little embarrassed, but I don't understand why this piece of code is not behaving as expected.

Looking at the debugger and console log, the length is 1, and the innerText = 'No record found.' I was expecting the if statement to be executed, but the else statement is executed instead.  To be sure, I logged the innerText and tr.length, and the result is 'No record found.' and 1 respectively.  What am I not getting here?

```
var tr = $('.users').find('tr');
if (tr.length === 1 && ((tr[0].innerText === 'No record found.') 
   || (tr[0].innerText === 'No matching records found') 
   || (tr[0].innerText === ''))) {
 //console.log('no record found is displayed.');
   $('.customTableInfo').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');                     
   $('.customEntries').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');                   
   $('.itemPerPageLabel').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');              
   $('.customPaging').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');
} else {
   console.log(tr[0].innerText);
   $('.customTableInfo').addClass('Display').removeClass('DisplayNone');                      
   $('.customEntries').addClass('Display').removeClass('DisplayNone');                     
   $('.itemPerPageLabel').addClass('Display').removeClass('DisplayNone');                   
   $('.customPaging').addClass('Display').removeClass('DisplayNone');
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerText`. It's not standard and doesn't exist in FireFox. The correct property is `.textContent`.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why don't you just use `tr.text()`?

Comment: @Barmar I changed the .innerText to tr.text() instead. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you need to use `trim();` to avoid white spaces

```
if (tr.length === 1 && ((tr[0].innerText.trim() === 'No record found.') 
   || (tr[0].innerText.trim() === 'No matching records found') 
   || (tr[0].innerText.trim() === ''))) {
```

and for this code

```
   $('.customTableInfo').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');                     
   $('.customEntries').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');                   
   $('.itemPerPageLabel').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');              
   $('.customPaging').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');
```

you can simplify it

```
$('.customTableInfo ,.customEntries , .itemPerPageLabel ,.customPaging').addClass('DisplayNone').removeClass('Display');
```

Comment: @JeanB glad it helped .. Very Good Luck :)